# Makefile wildcard function evaluates to true against empty string

Tags: unix, makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

Using GNU Make 4.2.1

I'm writing a Makefile, and I want to use a conditional statement to have make check whether it is on a specific remote server or not. I'd like to do this using the unix `HOSTNAME` environment variable. I also want it to run regardless of subdomain, so I use the make `wildcard` function.

```
ifeq ($(wildcard *.remote.server.com),$(HOSTNAME))
        echo "ON REMOTE SERVER"
else
        echo "NOT ON REMOTE SERVER"
endif
```

This looks like it would work, but on my local machine the `HOSTNAME` environment variable is not set and the `ifeq` test evaluates to true and prints `ON REMOTE SERVER`.

This doesn't make sense to me; `*.remote.server.com` is being compared to an empty string and should evaluate false and print `NOT ON REMOTE SERVER`.

Am I missing something about either unix environment variables, `wildcard`, or make conditionals, or all three?

**Edit**: Problem resolved. Learned that this is not the spot to use the `wildcard` function. Instead, used something similar to the following line
`ifeq "$(shell hostname | sed -e 's/.*.remote.server.com/remote.server.com/')" "remote.server.com"`

Based on this response:
[How to use bash regex inside Makefile Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365305/how-to-use-bash-regex-inside-makefile-target#comment83739300_48368151)

Answer (score 1):

You could just print the values of these things to see what they are.  Something like `$(info wildcard='$(wildcard *.remote.server.com)' hostname='$(HOSTNAME)')`?  The reason for this behavior depends entirely on your local system, which we do not have access to.

However, I don't see why you say that *`*.remote.server.com` is being compared to an empty string*.  You've written `$(wildcard *.remote.server.com)` and presumably you don't have a file that matched the glob `*.remote.server.com`, which means the `wildcard` function expands to the empty string.

I think you might be confused about what the `wildcard` function does: what did you expect it to do?  It has nothing whatever to do with hostnames.

Comment: Thank you, i'm totally misunderstanding what the wildcard function does here, and the meaning of wildcard expansion.